Trying to add a PDFView as a subview of a PKCanvasView
Trying to add a PDFView as a subview of a PKCanvasView to use with SwiftUI. I have this code on its UIViewRepresentable:
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKCanvasView{
    canvasView.drawingPolicy = .anyInput
    canvasView.tool = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: .black, width: 15)
    canvasView.backgroundColor = .clear
    canvasView.minimumZoomScale = 1
    canvasView.maximumZoomScale = 4
    
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "doc", withExtension: "pdf") {
      let pdfView = PDFView()
      pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url)
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        canvasView.insertSubview(pdfView, at: 0)
      }
    }
      return canvasView
  }

The result is black.
If I add a UIView to it instead of a PDFView, I see the view.
Yes, the URL is valid.
My idea is to be able to pinch zoom the drawing and the background at the same time.
How do I do that?
